# Backing up Windows machines using rsync over SSH

Tags: windows-xp, rsync

We have a number of Windows XP / Windows 7 machines which need to be backed up nightly to a Linux file server.

We would like to do it with rsync and rsnapshot as that's what we're familiar with already from the rest of our Linux/FreeBSD machines.

We tried DeltaCopy, but DeltaCopy proved to be troublesome- lots of problems getting it to log in via SSH automatically, and the Windows Scheduled Tasks seem to fail often.

Is there a reliable way/application which can back up Windows machines via rsync to a r

Comment: Have you tried [cwrsync](http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/10650)?

Answer (score 2):

You might try [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com). It will work natively with both rsync and ssh, and even has a cron daemon that you could use instead of scheduled tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [Unison File Synchronizer](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/).  I've had very good luck with it.

Comment: If you decide to use Union File Synchronizer beware of the fact there is no authentication on its daemon, allowing anybody accessing that port to read/modify/delete files on the machine, restricted only by the service account user rights.

Comment: Shadok this is not a forum, if you have a comment use a comment, if you have an answer create and answer but please don't mix the two up.

Comment: To follow up - according to the Unison manual (http://bit.ly/gK7Xu3), you can implement SSH authentication to ensure secure transfer of data.